# Does a sql server filtered index <> 0 performs differently than > 0?

Tags: sql-server, filtered-index

I have a table with an Id column.

This column always hold value >= 0 (there's no constraint to assert this).

I have an index on this column filtered for `value > 0`.

Could this index perform differently (faster/slower queries?) if the filter was `value <> 0`

Maybe one is a best practice and the other a bad one...

EDIT, I wrote this script:

```
-- Structure
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_Src]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_Src]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_Src (
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tst20150513_Src PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_1]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_1 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tst20150513_1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_1]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_2_1 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tst20150513_2_1 ON tst20150513_2_1 (ID)
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_2]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_2]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_2_2 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tst20150513_2_2 ON tst20150513_2_2 (ID) WHERE ID <> 0
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_3]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_3]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_2_3 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tst20150513_2_3 ON tst20150513_2_3 (ID) WHERE ID > 0
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_4]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_4]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_2_4 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_tst20150513_2_4 CHECK (ID <> 0)
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tst20150513_2_4 ON tst20150513_2_4 (ID) WHERE ID <> 0
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_5]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_5]
GO

CREATE TABLE tst20150513_2_5 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_tst20150513_2_5 CHECK (ID > 0)
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tst20150513_2_5 ON tst20150513_2_5 (ID) WHERE ID > 0
GO

-- Populate
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [type], [number],[name]) AS n
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS T
)
INSERT tst20150513_Src ( ID )
SELECT
    n
FROM CTE WHERE n <= 1000

INSERT tst20150513_2_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src

INSERT tst20150513_2_2 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src

INSERT tst20150513_2_3 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src

INSERT tst20150513_2_4 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src

INSERT tst20150513_2_5 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

-- Tests
PRINT '
tst20150513_2_1
---------------
'

INSERT tst20150513_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

ALTER TABLE tst20150513_2_1 ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tst20150513_2_1 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES tst20150513_1 (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

DELETE FROM tst20150513_1
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tst20150513_2_1]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_1]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_1] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tst20150513_2_1]
GO

PRINT '
tst20150513_2_2
---------------
'

INSERT tst20150513_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

ALTER TABLE tst20150513_2_2 ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tst20150513_2_2 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES tst20150513_1 (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

DELETE FROM tst20150513_1
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tst20150513_2_2]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_2]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_2] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tst20150513_2_2]
GO

PRINT '
tst20150513_2_3
---------------
'

INSERT tst20150513_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

ALTER TABLE tst20150513_2_3 ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tst20150513_2_3 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES tst20150513_1 (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

DELETE FROM tst20150513_1
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tst20150513_2_3]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_3]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_3] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tst20150513_2_3]
GO

PRINT '
tst20150513_2_4
---------------
'

INSERT tst20150513_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

ALTER TABLE tst20150513_2_4 ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tst20150513_2_4 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES tst20150513_1 (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

DELETE FROM tst20150513_1
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tst20150513_2_4]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_4]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_4] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tst20150513_2_4]
GO

PRINT '
tst20150513_2_5
---------------
'

INSERT tst20150513_1 (ID)
SELECT ID FROM tst20150513_Src
GO

ALTER TABLE tst20150513_2_5 ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tst20150513_2_5 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES tst20150513_1 (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

DELETE FROM tst20150513_1
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tst20150513_2_5]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tst20150513_2_5]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tst20150513_2_5] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tst20150513_2_5]
GO
```

And I'm a bit puzzled by the results:

```
tst20150513_2_1
---------------

(1000 row(s) affected)
Table 'tst20150513_2_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5006, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2018, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tst20150513_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1000 row(s) affected)

tst20150513_2_2
---------------

(1000 row(s) affected)
Table 'tst20150513_2_2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3004, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2018, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tst20150513_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1000 row(s) affected)

tst20150513_2_3
---------------

(1000 row(s) affected)
Table 'tst20150513_2_3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3004, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2018, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tst20150513_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1000 row(s) affected)

tst20150513_2_4
---------------

(1000 row(s) affected)
Table 'tst20150513_2_4'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5006, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2018, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tst20150513_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1000 row(s) affected)

tst20150513_2_5
---------------

(1000 row(s) affected)
Table 'tst20150513_2_5'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5006, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2018, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'tst20150513_1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1000 row(s) affected)
```

There are 5006  logical reads for tst20150513_2_1, tst20150513_2_4 and tst20150513_2_5.
Those table have in common that their index either is not filtered, either "combine" perfectly with the "associated" `CHECK` clause.

I don't get why those have more logical reads than the 2 other tables with indexed filters but no `CHECK` clause.

Comment: As far as I know fileterd index is fast to extract only data that you need. So I think that you have to answer what data do you want to extract. I don't really understand what data you want to extract. Of course you can have several extractions which covers each other. In that case you can consider creating several indexes - all depends of size and type of data (it will be read or insert and update) and space that you can sacrifice for addtional indexes.

Comment: I need to retrieve rows having id <> 0 yet since id value are always (non strictly) positives, I currently have writen "CREATE NONCLUSTERED .... WHERE ID > 0".

Comment: You should really only see degradation in performance where the Id column contains negative values for a filtered index with range `> 0`. If negative values are not supported i.e. in your case, there is no need to specify a range of `<> 0`. Having said that, for your example I would recommend setting the Id column to be the `PRIMARY KEY` but if you are not able then use a non clustered index

Comment: I am not sure if this will help - you can experiment. I think that if `negative values` can not appear you can set a `check` which disallow negative values and set `filtered index <> 0`. In that case it will be used to extract and must be quicker, but there are a lot of "it depends".
I am not sure why negative values in column with `filtered index >0` will have negative impact as @Geewers says.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov: When executed, the execution plan will perform an Index Seek which is more efficient if a given column contains a Filtered Index, and, the value is within the range of the Filter criteria else, a Table Scan will be performed which is less efficient.

Comment: Ahh, @Geewers, from that point of view I agree with your argument. But if he has only not negative values - he can change `filetered index` to `<>0`. Of course he must be sure that negative values can not appear accidentally.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov: Indeed he can :-), performance for his specific scenario will also be affected if a query happens to use 0.

Comment: If your index is filtered as id>0, don't query "where index<>0" even you know there is no negative id.  If your index is filtered as "id<>0", queries like "id>0" or "id<>0" are both good but"id=0" is not. Confirm your own results using the query plans.

Comment: what about when I'm not in charge of fulfilling the filter. Like a cascade delete where the referencing value has a filtered index? Will sql server ignore the index in one case?

Comment: In order to see more clearly this matter, I wrote a script with puzzling results...